# How would I monitor and test if my email service is running from end to end?

Tags: email, monitoring

I recently screwed up our DNS settings and managed to break our email. I blindly followed some instructions and added a CNAME record for the root domain. That effectively invalidates mx records and whatnot on that same root and screwed everything up.

It took 24 hours before I noticed the screw up. I need something that'll inform that email is broken a lot sooner.

I looked around the internet and found some services that check if your smtp and pop servers are running, but that isn't good enough. I want complete test that will send an email from a separate service and validates that it has been received.

Comment: note that "end-to-end" might have not noticed this any sooner due to the specifics of DNS propagation (cached records might be served for a prolonged period of time). So you might want to add specific DNS RR monitoring as well.

Comment: Here's a tip to avoid future DNS problems: Load your config to a separate DNS server which is reachable from the internet but not listed as authoritative for your domain. Then test the zone using http://dnscheck.iis.se - it has the ability to test on a different nameserver than the ones normally use. It would have caught this error.

Comment: [check_email_delivery for nagios](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Email-and-Groupware/check_email_delivery/details) Sends mail per SMTP and then receives via IMAP. Using it for my mailservers, works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script away in your favourite monitoring toolkit!

You need:

- a scheduled job that sends a SMTP message (for instance every minute) and then
- monitor the recipient mailbox via POP or IMAP (every X minutes) to see if it has received any new messages in the last X minutes (and delete those to prevent the mailbox from filling up).

No (new) messages received, raise an alert...

The above method is better for end-to-end checking of your e-mail, but not as good a  solution at to simply check your primary and back-up authoritative name-server and raise an alert when-ever the records for core resources change. Because even your mailserver may continue to use cached records and receiving email is no guarantee for correct DNS records.

Comment: Use `dig +trace +aaonly -t mx -q example.com. | grep ...` to see if your DNS looks OK from the outside.